# Custom Quantity into VF email

Tags: visualforce, email, email-template

Hello I have created a custom field for Quantity(under Order Product object) to get the number as integer. Through the formula-->number-->decimal=0 and had the Standard field Quantity. The result worked fine, instead of 3.0 I do get 3.

My problem is that I have tried to get the custom field into the template and when i use quantity__c , i still get 3.0 and not 3 as i get on the order product.
[image]
[image]

```
<td style="background-color: #BA4697; color: #FFFFFF">
                    <b>Description-Type of Flower</b>
                </td>
                <td style="background-color: #BA4697; color: #FFFFFF">
                    <b>Details</b>
                </td>
                <td style="background-color: #BA4697; color: #FFFFFF">
                    <b>Quantity</b>
                </td>

            </tr>
                   <apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.OrderItems}" var="lineItem">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                             {!lineItem.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name}
                         </td>
                         <td>
                            {!lineItem.Description}
                        </td>
                         <td>
                             {!lineItem.Quant__c}
                        </td>
```

Any ideas please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can format the Quantity in Output Text something like:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###}"><apex:param value="{!lineItem.Quant__c}"/></apex:outputText>
```

it may work.